# Calculate height of div's children using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to match parent's height with the total height of its' children, so the content does not flow out from parent's border. I'm using the following code :

```
 $("#leftcolumn").each(function(){
     totalHeight=totalHeight+$(this).height();
  });
```

Will it iterate through all the div's children? Sometimes, it works sometimes it doesn't.

Also, I tried following code, assuming it will consider all its children. But the result is strange and gives doubled height from the correct result.

```
 $("#leftcolumn > *").each(function(){
   totalHeight=totalHeight+$(this).height();
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty stupid question, but did you declare the totalHeight variable at the beginning? like " var totalHeight=0; " The second example you posted should work, but like jAndy suggested, you should use outerHeight() instead of height() for more reliability.

Comment: @ Kranu, 
Thanks for the comment - "Pretty stupid question" :)
Why you did you assume that I have not declared it at the beginning. I have mentioned that it works sometimes and sometimes it don't. I was not sure about how .each works. But, now I have figured it out. Anyways, you should expect such stupid questions from new ones. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey KutePHP, Kranu was probably talking about his own question, not yours:) It happens to us all to forget to init a variable, that's why we need linters and hinters:)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try it like so:

```
var totalHeight = 0;

$("#leftcolumn").children().each(function(){
    totalHeight = totalHeight + $(this).outerHeight(true);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/ takes `margins`, `paddings` and `borders` into the calculation which should return a more reliable result.

Comment: outerHeight does not take into account the margin unless you pass in the Boolean parameter "true", and it would be neater to use +=. Thus the second line should read:

totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);

Comment: Be sure to use `var totalHeight` above this somewhere so that your variable doesn't get attached to the window.

Comment: I also needed to prevent margin collapsing with an `overflow:auto` on some child elements, then all calculations returned correct values taking margin into account

Answer (score 8):

Another approach is calculating the distance between the top- and bottommost offsets within the element, **which would account for any non-static positioned elements**.

I've only tested this in one page and environment, so I'm not at all sure how safe it is to use. Please post a comment if be very bad codes or if it deserves some improvement.

```
var topOffset = bottomOffset = 0,
    outer = true;
$el.children().each(function(i, e){
    var $e = $(e),
        eTopOffset = $e.offset().top,
        eBottomOffset = eTopOffset + (outer ? $e.outerHeight() : $e.height());

    if (eTopOffset < topOffset) {
        topOffset = eTopOffset;
    }
    if (eBottomOffset > bottomOffset) {
        bottomOffset = eBottomOffset;
    }
});

var childrenHeight = bottomOffset - topOffset - $el.offset().top;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to ignore hidden elements, you can filter them out:

```
$("#leftcolumn").children().filter(':visible').each(function(){
    totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
});
```

Comment: You can short it to: `.children(':visible')`

Answer (score 2):

How about like this. Does not require you to mutate a variable in an outer scope, allows you to reuse the sumHeights function.

```
function sumHeights(height, element) {
    return height + $(element).outerHeight(true);
}

const outerHeight = $('#leftcolumn')
    .children()
    .toArray()
    .reduce(sumHeights, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#leftColumn').children().each(function(){
    var Totalheight += $(this).Height();
})var parentHeight = $('#leftColumn').Height();
if(parentHeight===TotalHeight)
{//Do the nasty part}
else
{//Do the Good part}
```

Comment: The variable would need to be declared outside the $.each loop, otherwise it will be overwritten for each child and not accessible to the outside scope. Also JS is case sensitive: `TotalHeight != Totalheight`, `$(el).Height() != $(el).height()`